,NET 8 Custom ILogger questions
I am trying to create a custom ILogger, but I am having difficulties with some of the concepts. Here is the sample code I have:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public sealed class AzTableLogger(LogLevel MinimumLogLevel) : ILogger
{
    public IDisposable? BeginScope<TState>(TState state) where TState : notnull => default!;

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel) => logLevel >= MinimumLogLevel && logLevel != LogLevel.None;
 
    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception? exception, Func<TState, Exception?, string> formatter)
    {
        if (!IsEnabled(logLevel))
        {
            return;
        }

        var message = formatter(state, exception);

        Console.WriteLine(mesage);
    }
}


How do I implement BeginScope so it can hold at least string values, that I can print in the Log function? I cannot find a sample implementation anywhere to be able to look at.
The default formatter that gets passed to Log is not null as I had expected, but it only prints the state and completely ignores the exception. If I call LogError and pass an exception it gets totally ignored.


How can I create a custom formatter for this? and
How can I inject it in the object so functions such as LogError can use it?

Thanks
